# Arcgis javascript api, show symbols according to zoom extent

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I am making a map based on arcgis js api. I have a lot of symbols drew on graphiclayer but they are too dense and even overlapping with each other.

How could I make my map showing less points if I zoom out and more points if I zoom in ? I think in this way, overlapping would no more exist.

Thanks.

Comment: how many point are we talking about and are they having the same symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at min and max scale of the GraphicsLayer object:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#maxscale

Then determine what scales are you interested in. This should stop the symbols from drawing if you zoom out too far out.

Comment: Thanks for reply but this method does not solve the problem above. For now, all my symbols are in the same graphiclayer, so when I zoom in/out, all symbols would disappear if I set max/minScale. What I am trying to do is less symbols, is there other method for this?

Comment: How about clustering ?

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html

This would aggregate points into clusters as you zoom out.

Comment: thanks @spiskula, that should work. And I find out if we want to make a zoom self-adaptive map, we should focus on arcgis desktop, making a good featurelayer. Only arcgis js api is not perfect enough. Thanks a lot.